# Show svg image in UICollectionView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, svg, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using svgkit, I am able to show svg image in the cell of UICollectionView via adding the svg image to SubView, but it gives me a buggy output, when I scroll up or down the images are getting added to cell making it plastered in the cells, and it also shows the wrong svg in every cell whenever I scroll up or down the UICollectionView, is there a way I could fix that bug? Thanks!

Comment: put your code...|| or give some screen shot

Answer (score 0):

It takes some time for SVGKit to draw your desired image.
If you scroll quickly the image drawn may no longer correspond as the cell may got reused for a different `indexPath`.

The solution is the same as when you load remote images (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37784212/1049134) which is also isn't instantaneous.

Comment: thanks for answering but somehow I got it solved eventually XD